# Django doesn't show selected choices in a Multiselect

Tags: python, html, django, plugins

Django multiselect doesn't return/render the selected choices that are saved in the database

form.py

```
class testform(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        temp = User.objects.values_list('username', flat=True).filter(groups__name = "Artist")
        OPTIONS1 = zip(temp, temp)
        self.fields['column'].choices = [OPTIONS for OPTIONS in OPTIONS1]

    column = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required = True, choices= [])
```

Selecting the options goes fine like

views.py

```
def index(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = testform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = testform()
    return render(request, 'dummy/index.html', {
        'edit_form' : form})
```

Data is being saved as once selected

```
['artist1', 'artist2', 'artist3']
```

But when revisiting the same page, it doesn't show the selected choices of that instance, instead the select multiple box has no selection of the above 3 choices

Retrieving view

```
def dummyedit(request, id): 
    obj = bfs_projects.objects.get(id = id) 
    if request.method == "POST": 
       form = testform(request.POST, instance =obj) 
       if form.is_valid(): 
           form.save() 
           return redirect('index') 
    else: 
       form = testform(instance =obj) 
    return render(request, 'dummy/index.html', { 'edit_form' : form, })
```

models.py

```
class bfs_projects(models.Model):

    column = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
```

A little help is strongly appreciated, 
Thanks in advance

Comment: The form you're rendering is initialised like this: `testform()`. So you're initialising it empty. If you want a form to show initial values, you can pass a `initial` dictionary. In your case you have a `ModelForm`, so you should pass it the initial *instance*: `form = testform(instance=MyModel.objects.get(id=<theidtoshow>)`. However your view doesn't refer to a specific instance it seems, so I have no idea which instance you'd want to show.

Comment: I do have the edit view, 

def dummyedit(request, id):
    
    obj = bfs_projects.objects.get(id = id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = testform(request.POST, instance =obj)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = testform(instance =obj)
    return render(request, 'dummy/index.html', {
        'edit_form' : form,
        })

When I render this view, it doesn't get the choices selected, sorry I didn't attach this view in the begining, thought it was understandable

Comment: then the index view is not relevant in your question since that's not the view rendering the page where you have the unexpected result. Add the correct view in your question.

Comment: Apologies for the mistake, added the correct view here

Comment: is `column` a field on your model?

Comment: Yes, column, a charfield

Comment: that's the problem, django can save the output of a form MultipleChoiceField to a char field, but not the other way round. The CharField is a string, not a list of choices.

Comment: Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: If you're using PostgreSQL, using an ArrayField instead (because you get a list), otherwise, you have to populate your field with an initial value yourself in the init. Or you can search for ArrayField 3rd party package that maps a CharField to an ArrayField (it's just a matter of `json.loads()` and `json.dumps()` so it's a fairly simple field)

Comment: OMG, thats a lot of work using MySQL, thanks